# Spring Data JPA - finding number of rows from the database

Tags: database, spring, jpa

I am a noob in Spring framework. I know there is the findAll method to query all the data in a database. Is there a way to count the number of rows in a database using the Spring framework and doesn't require to write a SQL query?

Comment: Use projections in criteria api

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a method `count()` in `CrudRepository`. You can check official [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html).

Comment: how to add condition to that count

Comment: You could just add something like this to your repository: long countBySomeField(String someField);